# node-gyp not linking libraries correctly on macos

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I'm working on a node addon but there is an error on finding libraries after building with node-gyp.

here is my binging.gyp file:

```
{
"targets": [{
    "target_name": "xaddon",
    "cflags!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
    "cflags_cc!": [ "-fno-exceptions" ],
    "sources": [
        "cppsrc/main.cc"
    ],
    'include_dirs': [
        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")", "lib"
    ],
    "libraries": ["<(module_root_dir)/lib/xaddon.so"],
    'dependencies': [
        "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
    ],
    'defines': [ 'NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS' ]
}]
}
```

This builds correctly and if I put so file in the root folder of the project, everything works correctly. But I want to run a project with files in lib folder.

This is the error when I try to run the project so files in the lib folder instead of the root folder.

```
Error: dlopen(#PATH_TO_PROJECT#/build/Release/xaddon.node, 1): Library not loaded: xaddon.so
Referenced from: #PATH_TO_PROJECT#/build/Release/xaddon.node
Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing with linked 3rd-party libraries is that you'll have to provide locations to search for them.
node addons are dynamically linked, shared libraries, so whenever you require an addon, the respective dynamic loader will have to load all required libraries.

### How can we check which libraries we require?

- macOS: `otool -L your_addon.node`
- Linux: `ldd you_addon.node`

In order to load these requires libraries, our loader is going to search in several places, e.g. in all paths listed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux.

But we're shipping our own lib, which is not in one of the standard search paths?

It is possible for a lib or executable (ELF format on Linux or Mach-O format e.g. macOS) to specify a [runtime loader path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath). These paths are hardcoded into the binary and may specify additional paths to search for libraries.

### How can we retrieve a binaries `RPATH`?

- macOS: `otool -l your_addon.node | grep RPATH -A2`
- Linux: `objdump -x your_addon.node | grep RPATH`

### Ok, `rpath` it is!

We can configure our `rpath` via linker flags:

```
"conditions": [
            ["OS==\"mac\"",
              {
                "link_settings": {
                  "libraries": [
                    "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path",
                    "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/..",
                  ],
                }
              }
            ],
            ["OS==\"linux\"",
              {
                "link_settings": {
                  "libraries": [
                    "-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'",
                    "-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'/.."
                  ],
                }
              }
            ]
        ],
```

### `$$ORIGIN`? `@loader_path`? What's this?

`rpath` entries are hardcoded, so having it fixed to e.g. `/home/youruser/libs/foo/bar/` will break as soon as you try to use your addon on a different machine.

Both `$ORIGIN` and `@loader_path` are token which our dynamic loader is going to replace with the directory containing our binary. So no matter where our library will be installed, if we specify paths relative to our binaries location, the dynamic loader will be able to find it. (`'$$ORIGIN'` is just a little workaround required so `node-gyp` doesn't mess things up when trying to substitute values)

A good read regarding this topic is [this article](https://www.lekensteyn.nl/rpath.html#what-is-rpath)

### Example

```
.
├── build
│   └── Release
│       └── addon.node
├── index.js
├── lib
│   └── my_library.dylib
├── package-lock.json
└── package.json
```

Our build generates the `./build/Release/addon.node` file, which is linked against `./lib/my_library.dylib` at build time.

Using `@loader_path` we can now specify an `rpath` relative to our binaries location, since `@loader_path` will be replaced with `/whatever/path/to/our/package/build/Release`.

```
              {
                "link_settings": {
                  "libraries": [
                    "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../../lib",
                  ],
                }
              }
```

At runtime, this will result in `/whatever/path/to/our/package/build/Release/../../lib`, exactly where our lib is located.

### What about Windows?

Windows binaries do not have / use an `rpath` property.

However, the [DLL search order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications) will start searching in the directory from which the application is loaded.

### A cross-platform approach

[My approach](https://github.com/nut-tree/opencv4nodejs) to shipping required libraries is as follows:

1. Link your libraries during build
2. Copy your libraries to the resulting output directory, e.g. `build/Release`
3. Set the `rpath` to either `$ORIGIN` or `@loader_path` on Linux and macOS

This way, we're instructing the dynamic loader on Linux and macOS to search for our lib in the same folder as our resulting binary, which is the default behaviour on Windows.

Copying files can be done via an additional target in our gyp file:

```
{
    "target_name": "action_before_build",
    "type": "none",
    "copies": [{
        "files": [ "/your/lib.dylib" ],
        "destination": "<(PRODUCT_DIR)"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. This really helped me to understand how linking works.

Comment: Interesting...  I've updated it to be like is described above, but it doesn't look like it's improved my own case.  Could very well be that my problem is not the same.  I'll have to keep looking for an answer, though I did have a question.  Could you in theory use `<(module_root_dir)` instead of the `@loader_path`? It does look like the `@loader_path` is for the Mach-O flavor of rpath token substitution, but would it be needed if the exact module root was supplied by gyp?

Comment: <(module_root_dir) would expand to a hardcoded full path in your binary. If it’s only for a single specific machine and its location is not going to change this might work out, although I wouldn’t prefer it.

You would for example already face problems when building your addon on a dedicated build host